# Do CVXPY support trace(X.T@A@X), where X, A are all matrices?

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I'm using cvxpy to solve some optimization problems, and I know they have quad_form() function for x.T@P@x, where x is a vector. I wonder if they also support when X is a matrix?

Comment: Is there any reason you did not try this out?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, the quad_form function does not support matrix. And simply writing x.T@P@x as objective/constraints does not follow their DCP rules. So I wonder if there is a way to work around.

Comment: You may add that information to the question. There may be some reformulations possible, but some example code and data to start with would help.